# Unable to delete empty S3 bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete a brand new S3 bucket using the following code:

```
public void DeleteBucket(string bucketName)
{
    s3Client.DeleteBucket(new DeleteBucketRequest() {BucketName = bucketName, UseClientRegion =     true});
}
```

The bucket does not have versioning enabled and has no files in it. I am able to delete it from the web interface, however, I am unable to delete it using the above code.

I get an AmazonS3Exception error with the error message "The specified method is not allowed against this resource."

ErrorCode is "MethodNotAllowed"

StackTrace follows:

> > at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.d__1a.MoveNext()
> >     in
> >     d:\Jenkins\workspace\build-sdkandtools\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet45\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonWebServiceClient.cs:line
> >     453    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
> >     was thrown ---    at
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> >     task)    at
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> >     task)    at
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     at
> >     Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.<InvokeConfiguredRequest>d__3`1.MoveNext()
> >     in
> >     d:\Jenkins\workspace\build-sdkandtools\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet45\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonWebServiceClient.cs:line
> >     274    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
> >     was thrown ---    at
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> >     Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.DeleteBucket(DeleteBucketRequest request) in
> >     d:\Jenkins\workspace\build-sdkandtools\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet45\Amazon.S3\AmazonS3Client.cs:line
> >     375    at WPFBucketManager.Service.AwsService.DeleteBucket(String
> >     bucketName) in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2012\Projects\BucketManager\WPFBucketManager\Service\AwsService.cs:line
> >     28    at
> >     WPFBucketManager.ViewModel.ApplicationViewModel.DeleteSelectedBucket()
> >     in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2012\Projects\BucketManager\WPFBucketManager\ViewModel\ApplicationViewModel.cs:line
> >     32    at
> >     WPFBucketManager.ViewModel.ApplicationViewModel.b__0(Object
> >     param) in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2012\Projects\BucketManager\WPFBucketManager\ViewModel\ApplicationViewModel.cs:line
> >     43    at WPFBucketManager.Infrastructure.RelayCommand.Execute(Object
> >     parameter) in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2012\Projects\BucketManager\WPFBucketManager\Infrastructure\RelayCommand.cs:line
> >     55    at
> >     MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource
> >     commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)    at
> >     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()    at
> >     System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()    at
> >     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
> >     e)    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object
> >     sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> >     genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> >     target)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> >     RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> >     System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender,
> >     MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> >     genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> >     target)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> >     RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> >     System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
> >     trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() 
> >     at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
> >     input)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
> >     inputReport)    at
> >     System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
> >     InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
> >     Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
> >     System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
> >     hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
> >     handled)    at
> >     System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
> >     Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> >     MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> >     IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> >     MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
> >     System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> >     callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> >     MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
> >     source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
> >     catchHandler)    at
> >     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
> >     priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
> >     numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
> >     Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
> >     MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
> >     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
> >     frame)    at
> >     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
> >     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()    at
> >     System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
> >     System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
> >     System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
> >     System.Windows.Application.Run()    at WPFBucketManager.App.Main() in
> >     c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2012\Projects\BucketManager\WPFBucketManager\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line
> >     50    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
> >     String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
> >     assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
> >     Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
> >     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
> >     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> >     preserveSyncCtx)    at
> >     System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> >     preserveSyncCtx)    at
> >     System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> >     System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

as requested, full code:

```
 public class AwsService
{
    private readonly IAmazonS3 s3Client;
    private const string AccessKey = "ACCESSKEYREMOVED";
    private const string SecretKey = "SECRETKEYREMOVED";

    public AwsService()
    {
        s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1);
    }

    public List<S3Bucket> GetAllBuckets()
    {
        return s3Client.ListBuckets().Buckets.ToList();
    }

    public void DeleteBucket(string bucketName)
    {
        s3Client.DeleteBucket(new DeleteBucketRequest() {BucketName = bucketName, UseClientRegion = true});
    }
}
```

DeleteBucket is passed in a string with the exact text of an existing bucket name (which is retrieved from GetAllBuckets().

Another Edit:

Using the following method to create a bucket through .NET successfully creates the bucket (refreshing the web console shows the bucket existing):

```
        public void CreateBucket(string bucketName)
    {
        s3Client.PutBucket(new PutBucketRequest() {BucketName = bucketName, UseClientRegion = true});
    }
```

Now, after confirming this can create the bucket, I pass the exact same bucket name into the above DeleteBucket method, and it deletes the bucket as expected.

To confirm: I am trying to create and delete buckets that are in the same region (RegionEndpoint.USWest2 == Oregon). Am able to create and delete via the library, unable to create from web and delete via library.

Comment: If there is a better way to format stacktraces someone please tell me.

Comment: Can you share the code that causes the problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of the bucket name you are trying to delete?

Comment: the example i've been using has been "isnor.textbucketa", having thought maybe the period was causing issues I tried "isnortestbucketa" and still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the AWS library and the entire issue was on my end. I was trying to select a bucket from a list to delete it, when stepping through the code one final time I noticed when "selecting" a bucket, it was never actually selected. What a foolish mistake.

If anyone else is getting the above error check to make sure you're not passing null in as the bucket name, that was my issue.